# How to fetch thumbnail from youtube embed for blogger?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, youtube, blogger

I'm currently developing a tube template for blogger. The concept is that I will be placing the youtube embed code in the post and it will automatically fetch thumbnail.

I've created summary post using below code (First thumb will be shown):

```
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1){var s=strx.split("<");for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){s[i]=s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length)}}strx=s.join("")}chop=(chop<strx.length-1)?chop:strx.length-2;while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' '&&strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1)chop++;strx=strx.substring(0,chop-1);return strx+'...'}function createSummaryAndThumb(pID,pURL,pTITLE){var div=document.getElementById(pID);var imgtag="";var img=div.getElementsByTagName("img");var summ=summary_noimg;if(img.length>=1){imgtag='<div class="firstThumb"><a href="'+ pURL +'" title="'+ pTITLE+'"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a></div>';summ=summary_img}var summary=imgtag+'<div class="post-desc">'+removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ)+'</div>';div.innerHTML=summary}
```

In the post, I've included a thumbnail and embed code. I'm trying to make a function to fetch thumbnail from embed code rather than uploading manually.

I'm creating the template from scratch. The link for my blog http://testingmicroviral.blogspot.com/

I was looking at the code below, but couldn't know how to implement it:

```
    var iframe           = $('iframe:first');
var iframe_src       = iframe.attr('src');
var youtube_video_id = iframe_src.match(/youtube\.com.*(\?v=|\/embed\/)(.{11})/).pop();

if (youtube_video_id.length == 11) {
    var video_thumbnail = $('<img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/'+youtube_video_id+'/0.jpg">');
    $('body').append(video_thumbnail);

    $('img:first').click(function() {
        $('iframe:first').fadeToggle('400');
    });
}
```

I have no idea on how to implement to blogger. Can someone help me? Thanks.